# Inconsistent keyboard layout on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, dvorak

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I have two keyboard layouts enabled in the keyboard options, English (US) and English (Dvorak). I have the option set to use the same source for all windows. When I switch to dvorak, some windows use QWERTY and some use Dvorak. Firefox and Spotify use Dvorak for a while and switch to QWERTY, while Terminal always uses Dvorak if I have it selected. I already tried uninstalling ibus (with apt) without success.

Comment: i have the same problem with german keyboard layout in terminal and english keyboard layout in browser, however, i set the language to german all the time.